# Unable to assign JSON object's property to another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building a [Weather App for FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/show-the-local-weather). Here's the [link to my CodePen](http://codepen.io/anishsana/pen/xRpeyp).

I'm pulling in my current location details from [this API](http://ip-api.com/json). I'm trying to assign the object properties from the results obtained to other variables but my webpage keeps breaking down. For example -

```
var city;
var location; 
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(a) {
  city = a.city;
  location = city;
});
```

The above code breaks my page with the following error in the console -

```
pen.js:14 GET http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/ec76a96f53a8031f8d1405309568a2711480895619856/Greenville 404 (Not Found)
```

The page works fine when I assign `a.city` to `city`, but only breaks down when I assign `city` to `location`. If I `console.log(city)`, it logs my city, i.e, the value from `a.city`, to the console. So all I'm doing is assigning the value of `city` to another variable `location`. What could be the reason this isn't working?

Comment: You're running into CORS related issues. Unless a site specifically permits it, you can't access their APIs directly from the browser.

Comment: You are getting a `404`, i.e., the URL does not work. That is why it is broken.

Comment: @Ouroborus I'm able to use their API without having to redirect it through CORS. For example. if I `console.log(a.lat)`, I'm able to log the latitude of my location.

Comment: @varlogtim I understand the error I'm receiving but it's only happening when I try to assign `city` to `location`. Otherwise the page doesn't break. For example, if I comment out `location = city`, the page renders properly.

Comment: @AnishSana The Codepen you provided doesn't function for me. Codepen shows an error instead of successfully running your code.

Comment: Ouroborus It runs successfully if you comment out `location = city` in the JS console. This is what I'm trying to figure out. It only breaks when I try to assign `city` to `location`.

Comment: `window.location` is a property on every scope. It will cause that codepen project to break when run in an iframe. [It is used to change the url the browser is currently on.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way your code is calling the information, you will need to nest a lot of your calls in those `getJSON` methods.
Assinging them to global scoped variables does not garuentee they will be defined once those functions are run.

```
var temp;
var latitude;
var longitude;
var city;
var region;
var country;
var location2;

$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(a) {
  latitude = a.lat;
  longitude = a.lon;
  city = a.city;
  location2 = city; 

  var weatherURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/station/find?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&cnt=1&apikey=[API-KEY]";

  $.getJSON(weatherURL, function(a) {
    temp = a[0].last.main.temp;
    var firstCelcius = Math.round(a[0].last.main.temp - 273.15);
    $("#temp").html(firstCelcius);

    $('body').on('click', '#c', function(e) {
      var fahrenheit = Math.round(((temp - 273.15) * 9 / 5) + 32);
      $("#temp").html(fahrenheit);
      $("#c").html(" &deg;F");
      $("#c").attr("id", "f");
    });
    $('body').on('click', '#f', function(e) {
      var celcius = Math.round(temp - 273.15);
      $("#temp").html(celcius);
      $("#f").html(" &deg;C");
      $("#f").attr("id", "c");
    });
  });
});
```

Also when accessing the variable `location` globaly it will access the global scoped [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) which will cause the url to change to `hostname/city`.

To use the api's however you must run your code **not** in codepen, but from a place not in an iframe.